# How I can simplify this?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement

I want to simplify these "if's", what are the variants? Thanks.

```
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = user_data[user_id]
    user.profil = message.text
    if not user.profil == '97':
        if not user.profil == '82':
            if not user.profil == '72':
                if not user.profil == '64':
                    if not user.profil == '45':
                        if not user.profil == '25':   
                            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
                            markup.add('97', '82', '72', '64', '45', '25')
                            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'אנא בחר פרופיל.', reply_markup=markup)
                            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_profil_step)
                            return
```

Comment: `if user.profil not in ...`

Comment: can you please write it in code? don't really understand

Comment: At the very least, you can just write `if user.profil != '97' or user.profil != '82' or ...:`.

Comment: (And nobody writes `if not ... == ...` in preference to `if ... != ...`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `not in` you can do it:

```
unwanteds = {'97', '82', '72', '64', '45', '25'}
if user.profil not in unwanteds:
    markup = ...
```

So this checks if user.profil is not in the unwanteds set. {} makes it set so lookup is somewhat fast.